# how to burn 9GB iso file on two dvds?

Tags: windows, iso-image, dvd-burning

I have 9gb iso file. I need to burn this on 2 disks such that while copying data from the dvd to hdd, it will automatically ask for "please enter disk 2" and then the data from disk 2 will also be copied.

Resultant data which is copied from the dvds should need not be in iso format. I tried to split it with winrar and then convert to iso but didn't work.

Comment: What is inside that ISO?

Comment: Most CD writing software (such as CDBurnerXP) can let you create a set of spanned disks, im sure?

Comment: 9GB is larger then the size of even a double layered DVD.  If you want to use optical disks you would need to use a Bluray disk.  If you can't use Bluray then create a setup executable and point the content to both disks the executable will do all the work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's not possible.

To copy files, you have to select them first, then selected files will be copied. Files that aren't on the disk won't be copied, because they cannot be selected, because they are not there. Simple as that.

Optical disks and OSes don't have any built-in support for data spanning over multiple disks. You could try to create some installer-like thing that will ask for next disks when required files are missing, but that won't have much in common with regular copy-paste routine which cannot be intercepted and modified to ask for further disks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [PowerISO](https://www.poweriso.com/) and a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnCxp3qXhmo) split big .iso file two .daa file. It may also be useful to you.